# Removing desktop components from a server

Tags: server, plymouth

I originally installed desktop ubuntu on a machine that I repurposed as a server.

I tried remove all graphics components from it. Qt, Gtk, and its dependencies I was able to remove.

When I removed all traces of X, it left me with a failing initramfs, because that depends on a spinner graphic, which depends on X11?

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
grep: /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth: No such file or directory
```

Should I run a different kernel for a server, that does not try to show a boot screen? Because plymouth seems to need its spinner, which needs X11 stuff?

```
$ sudo apt install plymouth-label plymouth-theme-spinner
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcairo2 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxext6 libxrender1
```

How do I reduce this install to server stuff only, without any traces of X11?